# How do i transfer images from Unity to Django server?

Tags: django, image, unity-game-engine, post, request

As it is, I want to transfer images from Unity to Django using '**UnityWebRequest.Post**'.
However, Request's dictionary(request.POST) in views.py was null.
Can I get examples(source code), so that I can get the ultimate inspiration?

i tried the C# source code as follows.

```
IEnumerator ServerThrows()
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath + "Sohyeluv.jpg");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("Things", 10);
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/testforunity/", form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError||www.isHttpError){
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!"); 
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of views.py on my Django server.

```
def fromunity(request):
    print(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse("h")
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried to do already?

Comment: I just edited it. May I ask for your advice?

Comment: what happens if you try to print "request" instead of "request.POST"?

Comment: just <WSGIRequest: POST '/testforunity/'>

Comment: Are you getting anything on django's side? Is the server receiving the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself. **Django HTTP 1.1 does not support ChunkedTransfer.** However, **UnityWebRequest in Unity will use this property by default**. So, if *UnityWebRequest.chunkedTransfer is false*, this was a problem to be solved easily. I would like to thank all the people who gave me advice.